# What is the difference is between something intercepted on the Session Layer vs. something that was intercepted on the Application Layer?

Tags: security, networking

What is the difference is between something intercepted on the Session Layer vs. something that was intercepted on the Application Layer and what happens if something is executed on a System under the System Account vs. what happens if the same thing is executed under the Network Account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSes have never implemented OSI layers 5, 6, and 7 as separate layers. In reality, there is a single layer for those three layers, and most people call it the Application layer. Some applications use protocols above OSI layer-4, but those are implemented in the application, not by the OS the way that layers 2, 3, and 4 are.

One example is how web browsers work. You can see that a web browser uses things that should be associated with the separate session, presentation, and application layers, but all those are rolled into the application itself.

Comment: I don't understand why you bring OSI into this. He didn't ask about it, and TCP/IP doesn't use it. I don't know why anybody talks about OSI for the last two two decades actually. It doesn't refer to anything real.

Comment: The Session Layer is an OSI layer. That is the only reason. My point that there is no separation between the OSI Session, Presentation, and Application layers directly relates to the question about intercepting traffic at the Session Layer vs. the Application Layer because those are not separate in reality.